# submit form action to an iframe?

Tags: html

I'm building a guessing game that works with user input. When the user inputs a word and submits, it should be taken to a new webpage with an iframe that contains a google page with the search for the element inputed.

For example, if I submit 'cats', i should be taken to a new webpage with an iframe that contains a google page with the search results for 'cats'

This is what I have now. It goes to said new page, but the iframe is empty. My question is: how do you submit the input to the google page in the iframe and redirect the user to the page at the same time?

```
<p>Choose search for <em>Player 2</em> to guess.</p>
<form action='https://www.google.com/search' method='get'>
    <input name='q' type='text' autofocus autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='search'>Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google probably doesn't like this sort of usage. Here is how Chrome's javascript console complains when clicking through from Bing to Google inside an iframe:

```
"(index):1 Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
```

Other than that, here is something that gets some content into an iframe based on user text input from the outer page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Clue: <input id="userInput" placeholder="Try entering: google" type="text">
    <hr>
    <iframe id="innerSpace" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
    <script>
      let is = document.getElementById('innerSpace');
      let ui = document.getElementById('userInput');
      ui.addEventListener('change', searchFor);
      function searchFor() {
        // generates an error page:
        //   `https://www.google.com/search/?q=${query}`;
        // this seems to generate some content:
        let query = encodeURIComponent(ui.value);
        is.src = `https://www.bing.com/search/?q=${query}`;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```